# HtmlRenderer.Utils.FontsUtils throw new exception mysql

Tags: mysql

MySQL is displaying error message on: HtmlRenderer.Utils.FontsUtils. Just found a solutions at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75673 and the following code. Anyone here, where to find the relevant file to make changes below:

In the FontsUtils class replace -

```
static FontsUtils()
      {
          _fontsMapping["monospace"] = "Courier New";
          _fontsMapping["Helvetica"] = "Arial";

          foreach (var family in FontFamily.Families)
          {
             _existingFontFamilies.Add(family.Name, family);
          }
        }
```

With:
       static FontsUtils()
         {
             _fontsMapping["monospace"] = "Courier New";
             _fontsMapping["Helvetica"] = "Arial";

```
         foreach (var family in FontFamily.Families)
         {
             if (!_existingFontFamilies.ContainsKey(family.Name))
             {
                 _existingFontFamilies.Add(family.Name, family);
             }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer on the same page:

If you go to codeplex and get the 1.4.14 version download that 
https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/releases/view/100328

open up the project and then do a search for 
static FontsUtils()
replace the code with what Michael Gaillez suggested
change the assembly version to 1.4.6 instead of 1.4.14 so that mysql workbench doesn't complain. 
Compile and rename/replace HtmlRenderer.dll in program files>mysql> [your workbench folder]>

After doing that it worked perfect in win 10.
Hope this helps someone, since this has been a bug since reported in jan...

Answer (score 0):

download new HtmlRenderer.dll from https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75673
replace at C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem when I have installed workbench on my Pc windows 10 which was solved by

**1. Download the new HtmlRenderer.dll**

Downloading the  HtmlRenderer.dll by clicking  https://bugs.mysql.com/file.php?id=22868&bug_id=75673

**2. Replace the File**

Replace the new HtmlRenderer.dll file in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

**Reference:** https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75673

Comment: If there is a link for OSX users looking to accomplish the same please post it.